# Active FTP client blocked by Windows Firewall on Windows 7

Tags: windows, windows-7, firewall, windows-firewall

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Active FTP client blocked by Windows Firewall on Windows 7](https://serverfault.com/questions/401304/active-ftp-client-blocked-by-windows-firewall-on-windows-7)

I have an application that runs as a service and contains an FTP client. It needs to connect to an FTP server that only supports Active FTP. When I attempt to get a list of files or download a file, Windows Firewall is dropping the incoming connection from the FTP server. (I don't believe we had this problem in Windows XP or Windows Vista.)

Active FTP is the protocol that requires the the server to open a connection to the client on a port that the client specified. (http://slacksite.com/other/ftp.html)

I know I could open up a large port range in Windows Firewall and force my FTP client to only use those ports, but I would have guessed that Windows Firewall would support Active FTP natively.

Is there some setting that needs to be made in order to have Windows Firewall automatically detect Active FTP and open up the necessary ports as needed? Can I change that setting programmatically?

Thanks.

PS- I asked this question on StackOverflow, but was told I should probably ask here as well.